# DataBinding() not working with Distinct() (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding

I'd like to create an application that reads data from a database and then shows it through a UI. The user then can add/delete/update fields and save it to the DB, pretty standard, right?

I have two tables: Motors and Measures. Motors table has a lot of fields, one of them is "company". Of course, there can be several motors from the same company, so I would like to filter those companies and get only the distinct ones in a comboBox.

I'm still playing around with the language and VS, so I've made a simple version of the UI where the user can add a new motor, in fact, the user can add the company field, because I'm trying to add a new company and see if it updates automatically in the comboBox.

For this purpose, I'm using Entity Framework and this tutorial from msdn for data binding:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx

The problem is that when I add a new motor (with a new company), it doesn't update if I filter the distinct ones, I mean, the following code **does** work and automatically updates the comboBox with all the companies:

```
        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _context = new MotorsContext();
        _context.Motors.Load();

        this.companyBindingSource.DataSource = _context.companies.ToBindingList();
        companyBindingSource.ListChanged += CompanyBindingSource_ListChanged;
    }
```

And the following **doesn't**:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _context = new MotorsContext();
    _context.Motors.Load();

    this.companyBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Motors.Local.ToBindingList().Select(x => x.company).Distinct();
    companyBindingSource.ListChanged += CompanyBindingSource_ListChanged;
}
```

I've created a ListChanged method to see when the software does detect that the list has, indeed, changed. In the first code it does trigger, but it doesn't in the second. Maybe the observer isn't detecting the change in the list when I add a filter?

```
private void CompanyBindingSource_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("List changed!");
}
```

And finally, the add motor button:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
    {
        Motor m = new Motor();
        m.company = textBox1.Text;
        _context.Motors.Add(m);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show($"New motor, id: {m.motorID}");
    }
}
```

With the first implementation, the comboBox does update and shows every company (for every motor):

Push add button -> "List changed!" popup -> "New motor: id" popup

With the filter:

Push add button -> "New motor: id" popup

In fact the motor adds, but it doesn't show until the restart of the program.

Any idea will be much appreciated. I hope I've explained myself well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line in the second example break the binding:

```
_context.Motors.Local.ToBindingList().Select(x => x.company).Distinct();
```

The reason is that the result of `.Select(x => x.company).Distinct()` is not a `BindingList<Motor>`, but a simple `IEnumerable<string>`

Use the following replacement:

```
var _companies = _context.Motors.Select(x => x.company).Distinct().ToList();

this.companyBindingSource.DataSource = _companies;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer DmitryG. I think that you mean _context.Motors.Select(x => x.company).Distinct().Load(). However, it's not working.The comboBox isn't filled by data. If I write _context.Motors.Where(m => m.company == "UPV").Load(); then I get a comboBox with three "UPV" (because I have 3 UPV motors). If I add a new one with UPV as company, it adds to the list, so I have 4. The problem is that if I had any other company, it adds also, so it isn't filtering company == "UPV" anymore. I think that the filter in the Load() sentence only applies in the first load, right?

Comment: >>I think that the filter in the Load() sentence only applies in the first load, right? Yes, you're right. You should reload the datasource from context after some changes.

Comment: Would you mind to explain in depth this? Do you mean that I should call _context.Motors.Select(x => x.company).Distinct().Load() from the AddButton also?

Comment: In general, yes you should. I suggest you to wrap all the operations with `_context` into separate class (ContextViewModel) and expose the Entities property which provides UI with actual data. Any operations, related to context modifications should be managed by this ContextViewModel and update this property's undrlying data .

Comment: @lyurealm I'm happy to hear that my assistance was helpful

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
this.companyBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Motors.Local.ToBindingList().Select(x => x.company).Distinct();
```

Returns `IEnumerable<T>`. In your case you want it to be list, so add `.ToList();`

```
this.companyBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Motors.Local.ToBindingList().Select(x => x.company).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. It doesn't seem to work even with .ToList(), though.